# How to find the output of contact form 7 shortcode?

Tags: php, shortcode, database, plugin-contact-form-7

I'm working on the website which is using contact form 7 and in that form they are using shortcode to display their own number, like so:

```
<fieldset class="precallback">
<legend class="top-section">Ring til os</legend>
<ul class="formlist">
<li class="textonly">Vita 34's kundeservice besvarer alle spørgsmål om stamceller fra navlesnoren. Vi ringer også gerne til dig i vores kontortid.<br />Rådgivning fra mandag til fredag 09.00 - 15.00<br />
[klickbarestelefon]
</li>
<li class="textonly">Ja, ring venligst tilbage</li></ul>
</fieldset>
```

But I just can't find where that `[klickbarestelefon]` comes from. I searched the whole admin panel, and database but couldn't find the output of it. Is there a way to find and change the output of this shortcode?

Comment: Have you considered using grep to search the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have FTP access (or the **WordPress** files) go to `wp-content` and search within that folder for a file that contains `klickbarestelefon`. You will find the file where the shortcode was created.

You add shortcodes on **WordPress** using this syntax:

```
add_shortcode("shortcode_name", "function_name")
```